Player names not syncing correctly in Mirror Networking in Unity
I am trying to make a multiplayer racing game in Unity  with Mirror Networking. I have got a player names system which sometimes doesn't sync the names correctly. When the host hosts the server both player names are the host's name, but when the host boots up the server again and client joins, the player names are synced. This is very confusing, please help!
This is the player name input manager script.
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Mirror;

public class PlayerNameInput : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [Header("UI")]
    [SerializeField] private InputField nameInputField = null;

    public static string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    private const string PlayerPrefsNameKey = "PlayerName";

    private void Start() => SetUpInputField();

    private void SetUpInputField()
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(PlayerPrefsNameKey)) { return; }

        string defaultName = PlayerPrefs.GetString(PlayerPrefsNameKey);

        nameInputField.text = defaultName;
    }

    public void SavePlayerName()
    {
        DisplayName = nameInputField.text;

        PlayerPrefs.SetString(PlayerPrefsNameKey, DisplayName);
    }
}

And this is the player script.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Mirror;

public class WheelController : NetworkBehaviour {

    public TextMesh NameMesh;

    [SyncVar(hook = nameof(OnNameChanged))]
    public string PlayerName;

    void OnNameChanged(string _Old, string _New)
    {
        if (!this.isLocalPlayer)
        {
            NameMesh.text = _New;
        }
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdSetupPlayer(string _name)
    {
        PlayerName = _name;
    }

    public override void OnStartClient()
    {
        base.OnStartClient();
        string playerName = PlayerNameInput.DisplayName;
        CmdSetupPlayer(playerName);
        SetDisplayName(playerName);
    }

    [Server]
    public void SetDisplayName(string displayName)
    {
        PlayerName = displayName;
    }
}


